# Should my child know their Family Account Apple Id password?

Tags: apple-id, password, family-sharing

My 8-year old child's iPad it logged in with their child's family account under family sharing. I am using a Parental Passcode to restrict access.

It seems that (according to Apple Support, a 'feature' since iOS 12) my child needs to enter their Apple Id password (twice) to initiate app purchase and once again (after parent approval) to finalize installation.

1) Should my child know their Family Account Apple Id password? What problematic settings could their potentially change knowing the password

2) Is this "enter the child Apple Id password 3 times" really a 'feature' as Apple Support claim, or a bug in my (freshly created) child's account?